# EOFException is never thrown in body error while reading a file

Tags: java, network-programming, pcap

I have to read in a specific network file and sum the data. I'm using  the pcap4j library for Java, and using a sample from the github host of the library to read in the packet file. I am using an infinite for loop to read the data, extract the protocol of each packet, then when EOF is reached, throw an exception that breaks the loop, but I am getting a compilation error that EOFException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement.

Handle has been assigned earlier to the following: The for loop is the start of my reading the file and packets.

```
finalPcapHandle handle;
handle = Pcaps.openOffline("final-name.pcap");




for(;;) {
     try {
        Packet packet = handle.getNextPacket();
        IpV4Packet ipv4 = packet.get(IpV4Packet.class);
        IpNumber prot = ipv4.getHeader().getProtocol();

        String comp = prot.toString();

        if(comp.contains("UDP")) {
              udp++; //variable to count
         } else if (comp.contains("TCP")) {
              tcp++; //variable to count
         } else {
              all++; //variable to count
         }

      } catch (EOFException e) {
         System.out.println("End of file");
         break;
      }
  }

  tot = udp + tcp + all;
  System.out.println("TCP: " + tcp);
  System.out.println("UDP: " + udp);
  System.out.println("All: " + all);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things are as simple as they appear to be. So it is here.

You get that error because, well, **EOFException is never thrown in the body of the corresponding try statement**.

The contents of the `try` block (in between the `{` and `}`) has a bunch of lines in it. Absolutely none of them could possibly throw this. The compiler is telling you that the `catch (EOFException e) {}` block is therefore useless code, it can **never** trigger.

I think you misunderstand how IP works. 'end of file' is impossible in that protocol. You just.. get packets. Any notion of 'end of file' needs to be encoded in the data stream itself. (i.e., `comp.contains("END")` or whatnot, and then set up the other side to send an "END" command.

Comment: Interesting, even if the file is a pre-determined length and handling offline? The two files I have only have a certain number of packets to them, not like a live capture. But I will experiment more with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only method here which can have anything to do with EOF is the method reading the next packet, i.e. `getNextPacket`.
From [the documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.pcap4j/pcap4j-distribution/latest/org/pcap4j/core/PcapHandle.html) one can see how `getNextPacket` behaves:

> public Packet getNextPacket() **throws NotOpenException**
> ...
> a Packet object created from a captured packet using the packet factory. **May be null**.

This means the functions does not throw an `EOFException` but can instead return `null` in case of no more packets.

There is another method though - `getNextPacketEx`:

> public Packet getNextPacketEx() throws PcapNativeException, **EOFException**, TimeoutException, NotOpenException
> ...
> EOFException - if packets are being read from a pcap file and there are no more packets to read from the file.

This method is clearly defined to not return `null` but instead to throw an `EOFException` on end of file.